Man catches a bird by putting glue on a tree branch
I am looking for a movie from which I only recall one scene.
The scene is set in a forest and there is a man, and perhaps also a child, who puts some kind of glue on a tree branch. When, later on, a bird lands on the glue-coated branch, the man picks the bird up and pierces its eyes.
Update:
It's not a recent movie, I watched it maybe 5 or even more years ago. I think I remember the characters using clothes from the XVIII or XIX century, pretty much like the style of Brotherhood of the Wolf

When did you see this movie? Was it old or new? Do you remember anything else (doesn't have to be a complete scene)?

It's not new, I think I watched it 5 years ago. Unfortunately I just remember this scene, but I think the movie was set on the XVIII or XIX century

I'm assuming you meant XVIIII or XX century, which would be 1800-1999. It's quite a span... If you remember how they looked in that scene (clothes, accessories, hair,...), you should be able to narrow it down quite easily. The period isn't that much of a help unless you can narrow it down and give us a time frame of one, or maybe two decades.

I meant from 1800 to 1900, since I remember the characters using clothes from this period. I think I remember some chariotes too, what makes me think of this period of time

The technique is called Liming or Birdliming.... in case that helps you find the movie.  A popular way of catching birds going back to Roman days.

Chariots would be earlier than the 1800's. For some reason this really tickles my mind suggesting Season of the Witch (Cage/Perlman), but I haven't watched it recently enough to recall a bird scene like that.

This sounds awfully close to a scene in Roald Dahl's The Twits where Mr Twit traps birds by spreading Hug-Tight Sticky Glue on the branches of a tree. Captive birds are then made into a pie by Mrs. Twit.
However... the idea for this book being made to a film has been in concept phase since 2003...
So I don't think it would be this... Coincidentally enough in 2003, a man was prosecuted for doing this very thing... 
http://www.peterboroughtoday.co.uk/news/local/court-man-used-glue-in-bid-to-trap-birds-1-56892
